# FFMPEG combining videos - returning video with black background?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, mp4box

I'm trying to combine two .mp4 files so they play next to each other in one window. They are the same length (9 seconds), have the same number of frames, and the sources are both independently playable. Here's what i've tried so far:

```
ffmpeg -i highres_BH_140.mp4 -i BH_140.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w" -b 16M combined.mp4
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i BH_140.mp4 -i highres_BH_140.mp4 -filter_complex vstack stacked.mp4
```

This just creates a video with a black background, although it does play for 9 seconds. One video is a higher resolution, could this be a problem? Or is it the fact that they're .mp4 files and not .mpg?

I'm still trying to understand ffmpeg's syntax, so it's possible I'm making a silly mistake somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Show the full console output.

Comment: [Crossposted](http://superuser.com/questions/1086931/combining-two-videos-results-in-blank-video)

Comment: vstack - **All streams must be of same pixel format and of same width**

Comment: I tried again with two videos that have the same resolution and got another blank video